# TextAlign isn't an available property for a TextBox if used from this.controls in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

Is there a way to center text in a TextBox if the TextBox is being accessed from the code below?

```
foreach (Control control in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    control.Text = "Test";
    control.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
}
```

An error comes up that says " 'Control' does not contain a definition for 'TextAlign'

Comment: `foreach (TextBox control ...`

Comment: `((TextBox).control).TextAlign...`

Comment: `foreach (var txt in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()) { txt.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center }`...(more)

Comment: @LarsTech - That works great! Thank you.